# Program that implements .CSV file data - Need assistance on implementing a Console.Readline() Method

Tags: c#, csv

I'm a novice programmer and I've recently written a C# program that implements .CSV file data which compiles correctly.

It functions perfectly and have met all but one of the requirements to complete this assignment.

The requirement is this:

"The program must allow me to pass a data-file name on the command line. If I pass the filename on the command line you must open that file for reading.(ie the .CSV file). "

I just don't understand how to implement a function that will be able to read the .CSV file on another desktop other than my own. I've been told that I would need to use the Console.Readline() Method but don't know where to start.

This is how I have it set in my current program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char choes;
            bool file_test = true;
            string file = "";
            var key = ".";

            {

    file = @"C:\Users\BorusseGooner\desktop\projectData.csv";

                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file));
```

This hard-coded path that will only work on my computer.

The receivables are: 
1. The program.cs file 
2. The .CSV

Any help would be greatly appreciated to revise my code to be able to be used & accessed on other computers.

Comment: _"I just don't understand how to implement a function that will be able to read the .CSV file on another desktop other than my own."_ - Your brief doesn't say that you need to do this. Don't you just need `file = Console.ReadLine();`?

Comment: `I just don't understand how to implement a function that will be able to read the .CSV file on another desktop other than my own.` the question just says open a path; I'm 99.999% sure it is just on your local machine (as every assignment I have ever done never used fileshares.)

Answer (score 0):

> "The program must allow me to pass a data-file name on the command line. If I pass the filename on the command line you must open that file for reading.(ie the .CSV file). "

This is knows as a command line argument, and has nothing to do with the `Console.ReadLine()` method.
Command line arguments are passed to your .Net executable using the `args` argument of the `Main` method.

If gives you the ability execute your program like this -
`c:\>YourProgramName.exe CsvFilePathToOpen` - where `YourProgramName.exe` is the name of your executable file and `CsvFilePathToOpen` is the path to the csv vile you want to open. Please note that since you're passing a path, you'll most likely need to wrap it with quotation marks, since it will most likely contain characters that can mess it up (like spaces, for instance) - so it should look like this:

`c:\>YourProgramName.exe "d:\Some folder\ some file.csv"`

In your code, you should check the length of the `args` argument, and if it has a length of at least 1, you should try to use it's content as the path, instead of the hard coded one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char choes;
    bool file_test = true;
    string file = args.Length > 0: args[0] : @"C:\Users\BorusseGooner\desktop\projectData.csv";
    var key = ".";
    //...  rest of the code here...
```